# std::initializer list from already existing std::array without enumerating each element

Tags: c++, arrays, initializer-list

Lets assume that I have a class with the following constructor:

```
class Foo {
    Foo(std::initializer_list<uin8_t> args)
    {
     ....
    }
}
```

and I have the following array: `std::array<uint8_t, 6> bar`.

Now I would like to create an object off `foo` with the `bar` array. Is there an other way as doing it in the follwing way:

```
Foo f (bar[0], bar[1], bar[2], bar[3], bar[4], bar[5]);
```

This way seems a bit complicated and it feels like this is not the way it should be.

So, can I create a `std::initializer list` from an already existing array, without enumerating each array element?

Comment: Why not just add a overload to the constructor set that takes a `std::array`?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Actually you can't explicitly create anything but an empty [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list), as there are no functionality to add elements to it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thats just because the `Foo` class comes from an other API so I wanted to know if I can use this constructor in a more effective way.

Comment: As for another possible solution, rather an adding an overload for `std::array`, how about creating a constructor taking a generic range using iterators? Though it only works if you can actually modify the class.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude also a good idea, but in this case I hoped that I do not have to touch the given API. But I will think about it. Thanks

Comment: And `Foo` doesn't have any other constructors or ways of initializing it that are more suitable?

Comment: At the moment there is only the empty constructor left which initializes the object with some standard values. But I will think about changing the API. Even if its a little more work for me than. I choose to ask this question here because I thought I might have overlooked something according to the constructor with the `std::initializer_list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do it.  This API which only accepts an `initializer_list` and has no facility to accept, say, a pair of iterators, or a pointer plus a size, is deficient.  You'll virtually never see an API like this in the wild.

Answer (score 2):

since you cannot modify "Foo" you can create your own `make_foo` method that automatically expands the array:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(std::initializer_list<int> args) {}
};

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
auto make_foo(std::array<int, N>& arr, std::index_sequence<Is...>) -> Foo
{
  return Foo{arr[Is]...};
}


template <std::size_t N>
auto make_foo(std::array<int, N>& arr) -> Foo
{
  return make_foo(arr, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

auto test()
{
  std::array<int, 4> arr = {{1, 2, 3, 4}};

  auto foo = make_foo(arr);
}
```